# Extract digits from a categorical column in pandas and convert to int

Tags: pandas, string, digits

I cannot see the flaws in the following snippet, but it doesn't achieve the purpose of replacing the strings with the digits it contains

```
data = pd.DataFrame( {'c':[np.nan, 'group 001', 'group 002', '03 group']} )

data[data['c'].notna()]['c'] = data[data['c'].notna()]['c'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
```

i.e., to replace the 'c' column by the values [np.nan, 1, 2, 3]

Comment: Works for me if I write the second line as `data['c'] = data['c'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)`.

Answer (score 0):

So, two things.

1. `df.notna()` does not drop nans, it just gives you a Series of True/False values (True if Not Na, False if Na)
2. I would drop the na's first, and then perform the replacement.

```
data = data.dropna(axis='columns') 
data['c'] = data['c'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)
```

and as a bonus, if you are getting the settingwithcopywarning, you can refer the a single column this way:

```
data.loc[:, 'c'] = data['c'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)
```